# Pandas change time values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'time':['08:45:00', '09:30:00', '18:00:00', '15:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to convert the time based on conditions: if the hour is less than 9, I want to set it to 9 and if the hour is more than 17, I need to set it to 17.

I tried this approach:

```
df['time'] = np.where(((df['time'].dt.hour < 9) & (df['time'].dt.hour != 0)), dt.time(9, 00))
```

I am getting an error: Can only use .dt. accesor with datetimelike values.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: You column `time` contains strings, not `datetime` objects. Convert them to datetime using `pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` first.

Comment: @rafaelc Thanks. I changed it but still not getting desired result.

Comment: Did you assign the new datetime Series back to the column? `df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`

Comment: @wwii yes I did, but I am only getting the hour value in the result. For example, 13 instead of 13:00:00.

Comment: Without changing anything could you please do "df[:5].to_dict()" and copy/paste in your question the output code please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.loc[df.time.dt.hour < 9, 'time'] = (df.time.astype('int64') + (9 - df.time.dt.hour)*3600*1000000000).astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.loc[df.time.dt.hour > 17, 'time'] = (df.time.astype('int64') + (17 - df.time.dt.hour)*3600*1000000000).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Input:

```
                 time
0 2022-06-06 08:45:00
1 2022-06-06 09:30:00
2 2022-06-06 18:00:00
3 2022-06-06 15:00:00
```

Output:

```
                 time
0 2022-06-06 09:45:00
1 2022-06-06 09:30:00
2 2022-06-06 17:00:00
3 2022-06-06 15:00:00
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's alternative code to try to address OP's error as described in the comments:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'time':['08:45:00', '09:30:00', '18:00:00', '15:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('', 'df loaded as strings:', df, sep='\n')

df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H:%M:%S')
print('', 'df converted to datetime by pd.to_datetime():', df, sep='\n')
df.loc[df.time.dt.hour < 9, 'time'] = (df.time.astype('int64') + (9 - df.time.dt.hour)*3600*1000000000).astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.loc[df.time.dt.hour > 17, 'time'] = (df.time.astype('int64') + (17 - df.time.dt.hour)*3600*1000000000).astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.time = [time.time() for time in pd.to_datetime(df.time)]
print('', 'df with time column adjusted to have hour between 9 and 17, converted to type "time":', df, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
df loaded as strings:
       time
0  08:45:00
1  09:30:00
2  18:00:00
3  15:00:00

df converted to datetime by pd.to_datetime():
                 time
0 1900-01-01 08:45:00
1 1900-01-01 09:30:00
2 1900-01-01 18:00:00
3 1900-01-01 15:00:00

df with time column adjusted to have hour between 9 and 17, converted to type "time":
       time
0  09:45:00
1  09:30:00
2  17:00:00
3  15:00:00
```

**UPDATE #2**:

To not just change the hour for out-of-window times, but to simply apply 9:00 and 17:00 as min and max times, respectively (see OP's comment on this), you can do this:

```py
df.loc[df['time'].dt.hour < 9, 'time'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({
    'year':df['time'].dt.year, 'month':df['time'].dt.month, 'day':df['time'].dt.day, 
    'hour':[9]*len(df.index)}))
df.loc[df['time'].dt.hour > 17, 'time'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({
    'year':df['time'].dt.year, 'month':df['time'].dt.month, 'day':df['time'].dt.day, 
    'hour':[17]*len(df.index)}))
df['time'] = [time.time() for time in pd.to_datetime(df['time'])]
```

Comment: On the first line df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time), I am getting an error: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime.

Comment: Is your `time` column of type `str`, as shown in your question?

Comment: Its an `object` type.

Comment: I mean, does it contain strings, or have you already converted the values to another type (`datetime` or `time`) before my code gives you an error?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything before your code. I implemented your code right after I loaded the data and when I loaded the data, the default type is `object`.

Comment: Without changing anything could you please do "df[:5].to_dict()" and copy/paste in your question the output code please?

Comment: I don't get an error in my environment, but I've updated my answer with an alternative approach that may work for you.

Comment: @constantstranger I had to change the dataframe notation from df.time.dt to df['time'].dt then it worked. Could you please tell me how do I set the minutes to 00? For example, 08:45:00 to 09:00:00? Thanks.

Comment: Please see `UPDATE #2` in my answer for a way to apply 9:00 as min time and 17:00 as max time, which I now understand is what you're asking.

Comment: Do you need any additional help with your question? If not, please consider marking one of the answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Since your `'time'` column contains strings they can kept as strings and assign new string values where appropriate. To filter for your criteria it is convenient to: create datetime Series from the `'time'` column, create boolean Series by comparing the datetime Series with your criteria, use the boolean Series to filter the rows which need to be changed.

Your data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'time':['08:45:00', '09:30:00', '18:00:00', '15:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string())

>>>
       time
0  08:45:00
1  09:30:00
2  18:00:00
3  15:00:00
```

Convert to datetime, make boolean Series with your criteria

```
dts = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
lt_nine = dts.dt.hour < 9
gt_seventeen = (dts.dt.hour >= 17)
print(lt_nine)
print(gt_seventeen)

>>>
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: time, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: time, dtype: bool
```

Use the boolean series to assign a new value:

```
df.loc[lt_nine,'time'] = '09:00:00'
df.loc[gt_seventeen,'time'] = '17:00:00'
print(df.to_string())

>>>
       time
0  09:00:00
1  09:30:00
2  17:00:00
3  15:00:00
```

---

Or just stick with strings altogether and create the boolean Series using regex patterns and [`.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern).

```
data = {'time':['08:45:00', '09:30:00', '18:00:00', '15:00:00','07:22:00','22:02:06']}
dg = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(dg.to_string())

>>>
       time
0  08:45:00
1  09:30:00
2  18:00:00
3  15:00:00
4  07:22:00
5  22:02:06


# regex patterns
pattern_lt_nine = '^00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08'
pattern_gt_seventeen = '^17|18|19|20|21|22|23'
```

Make boolean Series and assign new values

```
gt_seventeen = dg['time'].str.match(pattern_gt_seventeen)
lt_nine = dg['time'].str.match(pattern_lt_nine)
dg.loc[lt_nine,'time'] = '09:00:00'
dg.loc[gt_seventeen,'time'] = '17:00:00'
print(dg.to_string())

>>>
       time
0  09:00:00
1  09:30:00
2  17:00:00
3  15:00:00
4  09:00:00
5  17:00:00
```

---

[Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html)
[Working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how do I assign this to the original dataframe column?

Comment: Both of my examples show how to assign to the DataFrame using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a boolean Series for the row indexer and `'time'` for the column selector.

Comment: e.g. `dg.loc[gt_seventeen,'time'] = '17:00:00'`